# Error with ionic generate page

Tags: angular, typescript, module, ionic2

I need help making my module accept my newly generated pages. In my terminal I used the ionic command `ionic generate page` to create two new pages in my file tree. One called privacy-policy and the other terms-of-use.
It built the new pages just fine:

**privacy policy page **

```
/*
  Generated class for the PrivacyPolicy page.

  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-privacy-policy',
  templateUrl: 'privacy-policy.html'
})
export class PrivacyPolicyPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello PrivacyPolicyPage Page');
  }

}
```

**terms of use page**

```
/*
  Generated class for the TermsOfUse page.

*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-terms-of-use',
  templateUrl: 'terms-of-use.html'
})
export class TermsOfUsePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello TermsOfUsePage Page');
  }


}
```

But when I went to push the pages to a nav controller on another page. I got build errors in the terminal first that said `cannot determine module for component PrivacyPolicyPage` (and terms of use page respectively), then when I added the pages to the module in `app.module.ts`. I got an error that said `unexpected value PrivacyPolicyPage declared by the module AppModule`.

What am I supposed to do here? This is the entire **app.module.ts** file:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
   //other imports
import { TermsOfUsePage } from '../terms-of-use/terms-of-use';
import { PrivacyPolicyPage } from '../privacy-policy/privacy-policy';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        *otherPages*,
        *otherPages*,
        TermsOfUsePage,
        PrivacyPolicyPage


    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        *otherPages*,
        *otherPages*,
        TermsOfUsePage,
        PrivacyPolicyPage

    ],
    providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Could you please post the content of any other page that is working properly? It's just to see if you're using lazy loading in your pages or they're just regular components

Comment: what is your cli version? are you using lazy loading?

Comment: Are you calling the pages with this.navCtrl.push('TermsOfUsePage') or this.navCtrl.push(TermsOfUsePage)? First is lazy loading and is necessary to create a module for each page.

Comment: @spilot what is the file structure you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ionic generate page <page_name>` command will generate the HTML, TypeScript, and SCSS files for the newly created page in a new directory under app\pages.

To correctly address those components in your `AppModule` the imports must be like:

```
import { TermsOfUsePage } from '../pages/terms-of-use/terms-of-use';
import { PrivacyPolicyPage } from '../pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy';

// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure looks fine! I assume you are using tabs seed project from ionic templates. 
If yes, Make sure that you are using NavController to push and pop methods to change the view.

```
import {PrivacyPolicyPage } from "../privacy-policy/privacy-policy";
// Import statement for the PrivacyPolicyPage

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
//this.presentLoading()

}

// Method to load the privacy policy page
loadPrivacyPolicyPage() {
  // import PrivacyPolicyPage in the component 
  this.navCtrl.push(PrivacyPolicyPage );
}
```

Updated your CLI to the latest version using the below command. I was using CLI **3.12.0** version

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

Let me know if it works.